# How to refer to Couchbase API port other than 8092

Tags: couchbase

I am able to run application in my local m/c with localhost and 8092 port when my client and server are on same m/c.

But I have a requirement to deploy client and server on different VM and in VM we can't use the default ports of Couchbase.

Is there any way to point Java Client to port other than 8092?

I am using Java Client

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.couchbase.client</groupId>
        <artifactId>java-client</artifactId>
        <version>2.14</version>
    </dependency>
```

And `Couchbase Server version  - 3.x`

Answer (score 0):

There is an end point variable much like the one on the ["Couchbase Server 3.0/3.1 Developer Guide"](http://docs.couchbase.com/developer/dev-guide-3.0/connect.html) that references the port number.

You may change that end point to one that you are targeting other than the default.

Comment: I am facing issue in using Java Client SDK, it is polling view port `8092`, and I am not able to change it as there is no api is available for the same. But I am able to  change other ports e.g. 8091,  11210 and it's working.